# why python print " num += 1 " invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

```
balance = 5000
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.02
annualInterestRate = 0.18
num = 0
remaining_balance = 0.00

while num <= 12:
      remaining_balance = (annualInterestRate/12 * (balance-(balance * monthlyPaymentRate))+ tem_balance
      num += 1

print(remaining_balance)
```

why python print " num += 1 " invalid syntax ?

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis.

Comment: The `num += 1` is not where the syntax error is. Usually, the syntax error would be on the line above, and as already indicated by the previous comment. The line above is where your problem is, with the missing parentheses.

Comment: Many thanks for your reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing closing parenthesis on line above it.
`remaining_balance = (annualInterestRate/12 * (balance-(balance * monthlyPaymentRate)) + tem_balance)`